# Why did I got the ENOENT?

Tags: javascript, node.js

File `target.txt` and `watcher.js` is in the same directory `nodeex`. What is incorrect?

```
node --harmony nodeex/watcher.js
```

This is file `watcher.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('target.txt', function() {
  console.log("File 'target.txt' just changed!");
});
console.log("Now watching target.txt for changes...");
```

Comment: Because `target.txt` doesn't exist in the directory where you run the `node` command (which is the *parent(!)* directory of `nodeex`).

Comment: What Felix said. `fs.watch` is based off of your cwd when you launch `node`, I believe.

Comment: Use `path.join(__dirname, 'target.txt')`. `__dirname` is directory the current script lives in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 node --harmony nodeex/watcher.js
```

the command you are typing ok the solution that will always independent of your node file is to add the absolute path of your file

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 fs.watch(__dirname+'/target.txt', function() {
 console.log("File 'target.txt' just changed!");
 });
  console.log("Now watching target.txt for changes...");
```